# Use hashmap for Q&A program?

Tags: java, user-interface, hashmap

I am writing my final program for the semester and I wanted to get an opinion on something. I will be creating a GUI that will let the user attempt to solve basic math problems. I was thinking about using hashmap because it contains a key and a value. My thinking is I can display the question for the user and then compare it to the answer that is given. The questions have to come randomly. So do you guys think hashmap is the way to go or do you believe there might by a better way to implement it?
Thanks

Comment: Generally this kind of question isn't well-suited for stack overflow. It could work, but then again so could a hundred horrible ways of doing it, and in the end it all comes down to personal opinion.

Comment: What's wrong with a list consisting of a custom class that holds a `string equation;` and `double answer;` and just randomly retrieving a question from that list? Write down your options and see how they compare to eachother.

Comment: It's not clear how having a key and a value helps in picking questions randomly and comparing given answers with expected answers. What do you have in mind? Where is the code?

Comment: My thought process is, that is if I am understanding hashmap, is that I will have a list of keys and values. The keys being the questions and the values being the answers the correspond to them. That way if it would randomly pick one of the keys, the answer would automatically come with it. That way I could make sure that the correct question gets matched up with the correct key

Comment: @StevenEck: you can have the same result with a custom class, except that you can add more to that like feedback on a question.

Comment: What if you want to add new questions? Generally hard coding data into your program is not a good practice for scenarios like this.

Comment: So using a custom class would I just use two different arrays with the same amount of elements then compare, lets say, q[1] with a[1]?

Comment: No, you'd have a custom class that has a field 'question' and 'answer'. Then you'd put these objects in an `ArrayList` and you're done. This is just one approach, there are many possible. Given what you have told us, this might be the easiest one.

Comment: No no no. You would use a collection of instances of `Question`. Question being a custom class containing a `text` field (the text of the question) and an `expectedAnswer` field (the expected answer of the question). And you can add as many useful methods you want oin this object. Java is an OO language. Define your own classes, use encapsulation.

Comment: I would use an embedded database like hsqldb or h2 for the questions and answers. Then you choose to either retrieve them as a string representation/custom class, according to your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's basic math problems you want to test the user on, I would recommend coming up with question data dynamically (and the same goes for evaluating the answers). If you have different types of questions (say, division, exponentials, logarithms etc.), you should write classes for those. All of them could inherit from an abstract `Question` class.

So something like:

```
public abstract class Question{
    // ... general question fields and methods.
    String question;
    double answer;

    public boolean evaluate(double input){
        if (input == this.answer) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
}

public class LogarithmQ extends Question{

    // Declare relevant fields such as x, y, ... , answer

    // Define a constructor that generates random numbers to populate fields
    // so that every question 'object' is different.

    // also have an "evaluate()" method that 
    // takes as input the user's answer
    // and returns true/false based on the correct answer value
}

public class AdditionQ extends Question{
    // similar stuff here
}
```

This approach will be useful if you want your application to automatically generate fresh data every time it is run.

Now for the GUI, you can instantiate several different types of question objects and store them in a list. Since each object contains the question AND the answer, and extends the abstract `question` class, you will have a proper and easy interface to work with.

This is, of course, only a suggestion. There will be several differing opinions on this approach.

Comment: Gee whiz I didn't expect all that. Thank you. I am going digging through the Java API. This is my second semester and the first semester we were directed to check things out in there. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think is better use a Class that stores the question and the answer, and than have a list of them. So you can also encapsulate the routines to test if the answer is right and any other things you need.